# Как преобразовать многомерный список в одномерный?

Tags: python, массивы, список

Имеем многомерный список:

```
[0,
 [0,38.0, -38.0],
 [0,4.0,-4.04],
 [0],
 [0, -30.5],
 [0],
 [0],
 [0,21.7,2.7,-14.7]]
```

Как преобразовать его в обычный (одномерный) список `a = []`?

Ожидаемый результат:

```
[0,0,38.0,-38.0,0,4.0,-4.04,0,0,-30.5,0,0,0,21.7,2.7,-14.7]
```

Comment: Много раз спрашивали, поищите дубликаты

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) если максимальная глубина вложенности - 1:

```
res = []
for x in lst:
    res.extend(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x])
```

результат:

```
In [46]: res
Out[46]: [0, 0, 38.0, -38.0, 0, 4.0, -4.04, 0, 0, -30.5, 0, 0, 0, 21.7, 2.7, -14.7]
```

---

[Универсальное решение для списков с любой глубиной вложенности](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/5741205):

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

Пример:

```
In [54]: res = list(flatten([1, [2, 3], [4, [5, [6, 7], 8, [9, [10, [11]]]]]]))

In [55]: res
Out[55]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(arr0):
    arr1 = [] #создадим пустой массив
    for i in arr0: #пройдёмся по всем элементам входного массива
        if type(i) != list:
            arr1.append(i) #если тип не list то в arr1 добавляем i
        else:
            arr1 += f(i) #иначе запускаем функцию для i
    return arr1
```

вывод:

> `[0, 0, 38.0, -38.0, 0, 4.0, -4.04, 0, 0, -30.5, 0, 0, 0, 21.7, 2.7, -14.7]`

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin добавил комментарии

Comment: _добавил комментарии_, я уже вроде писал вам, почему желателено пояснение к коду. Комментарии в коде, это всё ещё код. Тем боле, не надо подавать пример новичкам - код нуждающийся в комментариях, это плохой код.